# Remove -r-00000 on Reducer output

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, multipleoutputs

I am using MultipleOutputs like this:

```
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ...
        job1.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job1.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);          

        ****MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job1, "stopwords", TextOutputFormat.class, Text.class, IntWritable.class);****
        ...
}
```

On the Reducer

```
public static class ReduceWordCount extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {  
    private MultipleOutputs<Text, IntWritable> mos;
    @Override
    public void setup(Context context) {
         mos = new MultipleOutputs<Text, IntWritable>(context);
    }
    @Override
    public void reduce(Text word, Iterable<IntWritable> counts, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        for (IntWritable count : counts) {
            sum += count.get();
        }
        if(sum>4000){
            context.write(word, new IntWritable(sum));
            mos.write("stopwords", new Text(word+", "), sum, "stopwords.csv");
        }
    }
    protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        mos.close();
    }
}
```

**The output file i get is stopwords.csv-r-00000**
I need to get rid off the -r-00000. How can i do that?

Comment: How many reducers do you have? If you have more than 1 reducer, and you don't have the `-r-00000` segment, it will fail

Answer (score 0):

To whom it may concern i found an answer [here](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/86436/how-to-remove-r-00000-extention-from-reducer-outpu.html) where he renames the file after job is finished

```
    FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(getConf());
    FileStatus fs[] = hdfs.listStatus(new Path(args[1]));
    if (fs != null){ 
    for (FileStatus aFile : fs) {
        if (!aFile.isDir()) {
            hdfs.rename(aFile.getPath(), new Path(aFile.getPath().toString()+".txt"));
        }
    }
}
```